# How to select nearby text with the same format

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to select **text block around the cursor with** **the same format** (e.g. the same color, size, font, italic, bold) using macro. The text may contain space. For example, in the following, I want to select the whole green text with the cursor (but I don't want to select the other green text without the cursor). Thanks!

> [image]

Comment: Will the text be to select always be green or was that just for the example?  If not, what are the rules for choosing what to select?   Multiple words, both directions, certain colors but not others, far, but not _too_ far?  :-)  The more examples you can provide, the better.  Have you tried anything?

Comment: @ashleedawg Thanks for your comment. I edited my question and hope it is more clear this time. It does not need to be "green" as in the example, but the whole selected text need to be of the same format.

Comment: of **which** format?  Color, size, font, italic, bold, character set, or just _any_ change to the formatting at all?  Should it stop at the math symbols or include them like regularly formatted text?  It can have a space, but can it have 2 spaces?  3?  Should it stop at the end of the line?  paragraph?  Brackets?  Is there a maximum or minimum number of characters? ...A solution is prone to interpretation.  Could you give a few more examples?

Comment: Kerning, Fill, Shading, Engrave, Underline, Glow, SizeBi, Subscript, DoubleStrikeThrough, Duplicate, Hidden, AllCaps, Spacing, Superscript, TextShadow, EmphasisMark, Position, SmallCaps, UnderlineColor, Shrink, Outline, ItalicBi, Creator, BoldBi, Borders, Reflection, DiacriticColor, Size, Shadow, ThreeD, Reset, Emboss, Italic, SetAsTemplateDefault, Bold, TextColor, Grow...    **okay** I'll stop. :-)  Point is, formatting is a general term and what's obvious to one person might not be for another.  Without more background info & more than 1 example, its hard to help.

Comment: Also how do the parts of text which you want to be selected differ from the others? if you say you want the one green, bold, italic text to be selected but not the other which is also green, bold, italic, you need to have something where they differ. Or you have to be able to give a section, where text of the specific format has to be selected to limit the selection to the section specified...